# Extracting address with Regex

Tags: regex

I'm trying to looking for `Street|St|Drive|Dr` and then get all the contents of the line to extract the address:

```
(?:(?!\s{2,}|\$).)*(Street|St|Drive|Dr).*?(?=\s{2,})
```

.. but it also matches:

```
Full match  420-442 ` Tax Invoice/Statement`
Group 1.    433-435 `St`

Full match  4858-4867   `163.66 DR`
Group 1.    4865-4867   `DR`

Full match  11053-11089 ` Permanent Water Saving Plan, please`
Group 1.    11077-11079 `Pl`
```

How do i match only whole words and not substrings so it ignores words that `contain` those words (the first match for example).

Comment: Please provide sample input and output.

Comment: Sure: https://regex101.com/r/3yq6dD/1

Comment: [Here is the best I could quickly whip up](https://regex101.com/r/3yq6dD/3), given the limited example text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to use the the word-boundary anchor, `\b`, to accomplish this:

```
(?:(?!\s{2,}|\$).)*\b(Street|St|Drive|Dr)\b.*?(?=\s{2,})
```

If you provide an example of the raw text you're parsing, I'll be able to give additional help if this doesn't work.

---

Edit: 
From [the link you posted in a comment](https://regex101.com/r/3yq6dD/1), it seems that the `\b` solution solves your question:

> How do i match only whole words and not substrings so it ignores words that contain those words (the first match for example).

However, it seems like there are additional issues with your regex.